# How to get deleted files into a log file. Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

So im using the script

```
find /path/to/files/* -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

How can i collect the deleted files and transfer them into a logfile in Bash script

Comment: I am assuming you meant to put space between "find" and "/path..."?

Comment: Just add `-print` to your `find` command, then redirect the command's output to a file. `>logfile.txt find /path/to/files/* -mtime +60 -print -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Also you can just use the `-delete` action rather than `-exec rm {} \;` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
find /path/... -print ... | tee -a <log.file>
```

The `-print` will print out all the hits, and the `tee` will append that to some log.file.

Side note: the `*` at the end of your `/path/to/files/*` seems superfluous.

Side note2: if you just want to delete the files, `find` has a built-in `-delete`.